# Tile divs equal height on last row of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys is there a way around to achieved the following design?
i make a design of my div but i don't know how to get it like this.divs are in the center of the page and the width of the wrapper of all this divs can be adjust.

[image]

Normal content

[image]

When the wrapper becomes smaller then it will be a two column div and the last are still equal.
 * wrapper div adjust its width when zoom in and zoom out..

[image]

CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/ui-layout.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/layout.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/js/equalheight.js"></script>

<style>
 html,body{
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   min-width: 820px;
   color: #333333;
   background-color: #F1F1f1;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 13px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
        color:#3EA7bb;
        cursor: pointer;
}

ul{
    display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
}

hr{
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.cleared
{
   display:block;
   clear: both;
   float: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: none;
   font-size: 0;
   height:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.reset-box
{
   overflow:hidden;
   display:table;
}

#main-container{
   width: 80%;
   min-height: 100%; 
    min-width: 820px;
    max-width: 1000px;
   z-index: 0;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   cursor:default;
   overflow:hidden;  
   background-color:#FFFFFF; 
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto; 
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333333; 
}

#header{

    height: 100px; 

    padding-top: 5px; 
    margin:0 auto;  
}
#header-logo{
    width: 308px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(../images/skerp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
#menu-bar{ 

   margin:0 auto; 
   min-height: 25px;
   z-index: 100;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0; 
   border-radius:0px;
   /*-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #333333;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #333333;*/
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin:0 auto; 

} 
#menu-wraper{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
.menu-element{ 
    min-width: 75px;
    height: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;  
    text-align:center;
} 

#body-container{

    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 90px;  
}


.left-container,.right-container,.center-container{
    display: block;
    float:left;

} 
.featured{
margin:20px auto;
padding:5px; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #333333;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333333; 
border-radius: 5px;
min-height: 300px;
width: 780px;
}

.left
{ 
    text-align: left; 
}
.left span{
    float:left;
    left:0;
}
.right
{ 
    text-align: right; 
}
.right span{
    right:0; 
    float:right;
}
.main-under-color{
    width: 300px;
    height:5px;
    display: block;
}
.sub-under-color{
    width: 100px;
    height:5px;
    display:  block; 
}
.content-wrapper{
    margin:10px auto;
    min-width: 810px; 
    /*padding:10px;*/ 
}

.content-wrapper h1{
    text-align: left;
}
.image-wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.page-title{   
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px; 
    display: block; 
}
.page-title h1{
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 40px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.content-title h1{
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.content{ 
    padding:0px;/* 15px  15px 15px;*/
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;  
}
.content p{
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 25px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    word-wrap:break-word; 
}
.border{  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #999999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #999999; 
}

.border-top{
    border-top:1px solid #999999; 
}
.border-left{ 
    border-left:1px solid #999999; 
}
.border-right{  
    border-right: 1px solid #999999; 
}
.border-bottom{  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; 
}


   .column-wrapper{
       padding-top: 20px;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align:middle;
       width:100%;    

    }

    .column-wrapper div{ 
        display: inline-table;
        margin:2px;  


    }
    .column-small{
        padding:10px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
        width:30%; 
        min-width: 250px; 
        position: relative;  
    } 

     .fixedbottomReadMore{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 20px;
    } 
     .fluedbottomReadMore{
        position: absolute;
        float:right;
        right:20px;
    } 
    .column-small ul{
        margin-top: -10px;
        width: 100%; 
        max-width: 240px;
    }
    .column-small ul li{
        text-align: left;  
    }
    .column-small li{ 
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px;
        text-indent: -30px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .column-medium{

    padding:10px;
        width: 61%;
        min-width: 505px;
    }
    .column-large{
    padding:10px;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 760px; 
    }



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-container">


    <div id="body-container" > 

        <div class="content-wrapper ">  
            <div class="cleared"></div>
                <div class="content ">

                    <div class="cleared"></div>
                    <div class="column-wrapper ">
                        <div class="column-large "> 

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cleared"></div>
                    <div class="column-wrapper"> 
                        <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
                            <h3>Features</h3> 
                             <ul>
                                 <li>Code blocking</li>
                                 <li>Code Wrapping</li>
                                 <li>Code Killing</li>
                                 <li>Code Sleeping</li>
                             </ul>
                            <span class="fixedbottomReadMore"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
                            <h3>Modules</h3>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>Barking Around The house</li>
                                 <li>Loving the Cats</li>
                                 <li>Floating The points</li>
                                 <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
                                 <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
                             </ul>
                             <span class="fixedbottomReadMore"><a href="#">Read more</a></span> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
                             <h3>Idont knows</h3>
                             <span class="fixedbottomReadMore"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
                            <h3>Modules</h3>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>Barking Around The house</li>
                                 <li>Loving the Cats</li>
                                 <li>Floating The points</li>
                                 <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
                                 <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
                             </ul>
                             <span class="fixedbottomReadMore"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
                             <h3>Idont knows</h3>
                             <span class="fixedbottomReadMore"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div> 
        </div>
        <script>
            $('.column-wrapper .column-small').equalHeightColumns();
        </script>
    </div>  
    <div class="cleared reset-box"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean, but from your drawing it seems what you're trying to achieve is a "masonry layout" similar to Pintrest. Check out this link and see if it helps: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: Thanks jeff. that is what i am trying to achieve, but i want the last div bottom part should align. No empty spaces.

Comment: I think I have made a similar layout, Can you post your markup?

Comment: what do you mean mark up is source code?

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net would be better my friend.. anyways.. I ll see what I can do

Comment: oh..im so sorry ..i not familiar of jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24610/discussion-between--and-snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this fits your scenario, however, the fiddle below sligns the bottoms of the DIV.

The thing I am unsure about is, when you convert it to two column model, what all blocks will be visible, if you end up showing two blocks in the last row, then the bottoms will get aligned to bottom.

See if this helps - http://jsfiddle.net/AUV7J/

Making the `span` as `display: table-cell`, we can vertically align the block inside it to the bottom

**Update:**

As you said, you don't want spaces in between. You will have to programatically adjust the size of the last `DIV` for each column

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUV7J/2/)

**Update:**

For dynamic columns, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AUV7J/7/)

Comment: You can render the columns dynamically like this http://jsfiddle.net/AUV7J/7/, I was too lazy to make the blocks as elements, so kept it as string, you can optimize that, but the working is as you wanted it

Answer (score 1):

I would bind a function to the window resize event like so...

```
var $win = $(window),
    maxHeight,
    mode,
    calcMaxHeight = function() {
        var h = $(this).height();
        if (h > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = h;
        }
    },
    adjustDivHeights = function() {
        var $col = $(this);
        if ($col.height() < maxHeight) {
            var $lastChild = $col.children().last();
            $lastChild.height(maxHeight - ($col.height() - $lastChild.height()));
        }
    };

$win.resize(function() {
    if ($win.width() > 500) {
        if (mode === 'large') return;
        mode = 'large';
        maxHeight = 0;
        $('#container').children().each(calcMaxHeight).each(adjustDivHeights);
    } else {
        if (mode === 'small') return;
        mode = 'small';
        maxHeight = 0;
        // other size logic
    }
});
```

The event only fires the calculations if/when you switch modes, for efficiency sake, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of every last content base on the browser's window since you have a fixed number of contents horizontally, you can make a calculations and make it handy for the last contents. That's my best idea i get so far.